# J Button grid (how to dynamically create J Buttons in java)

Tags: java, grid, jbutton

i am new to programming and i would like to create a grid of thousands of J Buttons with action listeners that are all the same but they work independently without having to code each one of them. how would i archive that

Comment: Higher some one...a `for-loop` comes to mind...

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want a grid of 1000 JButtons? You could only ever interact with several at a time. Something tells me that this design is broken and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hovercraft Full Of Eels` is correct. You need to re-think what you are trying to do, it is a nasty waste of resources, and is a disaster waiting to happen.

You would be better to create a [glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) that can capture action events and trigger actions depending on their co-ordinates. That would use a single action listener, rather than what you want with over 1000 action listeners.

If you want visual effects, then simply override the `paint(Graphics g)` method of the container that you want to put the buttons into: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

However the following demonstrates what you have asked for. It uses a for loop to create a grid of buttons in a [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), but i strongly recommend against it:

```
public static void createGrid(JPanel panel, int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
{
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns));
    for (int c = 0; c < numberOfColumns; c++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < numberOfRows; r++)
        {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
            //Add your code here for action event
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        }
    }
}
```